# Replace special character dashes with dashes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just wanted to get advise about this matter from you all. So a lot of our clients do massive imports into the database. Now on one instance the client updated a particular column with around 10000 rows in it. They were trying to add fields ( Sample shown below)

```
ABC - TEST - TN - ABC D123
```

Now while they were importing all this in the system, the dashes were basically changed into special characters , not sure as to how that happened because when i import the file from the system again it displays funny symbols instead of just a '-' . Now I want to mass update all the data in the columns. I was thinking something like

```
   UPDATE ABC
   SET columnname = replace(columname,''-'',''-'')
```

Any ideas on this matter would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: My guess is they are "microsoft" dashes, possibly created by Excel or Word. Just find out what the characters are and replace them with normal dashes after loading.

Comment: Looking at your example, all of the dashes are coming up as CHAR(45) which is a "normal dash".

Comment: @JasonA.Long Yea I saw that too. The thing is that the row count is very big. Can i iterate through the column itself in order to determine where that special character is ?

Comment: At this point, all you need to do is figure out what the ASCII or UNICODE value is so that you can do the replace... So for your example (dash in the 5th position) execute the following... SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(tn.Value, 5, 1)), UNICODE(SUBSTRING(tn.Value, 5, 1)) FROM dbo.TableName tn WHERE tn.ID = [a row that you know to have the funky character];... From there, look at @john Cappelletti's awswer...

Comment: @JasonA.Long - Thank you for help. I did write some code. Now the issue here is the one that you mentioned with the Substring is fine for my above example. But there are instances when these characters are at random places in different columns. And there are instances where there are many special characters in them. How can i look for each special character inside the string and return their position and unicodes for each one.

select Unicode(CHARINDEX('-', abc.xrefcode)) AS UNICODENUMBER, ASCII(CHARINDEX('-', abc.xrefcode)) AS ASCIICODE,
(CHARINDEX('-', abc.xrefcode)) INDEXNO from abc

Comment: Just posted an answer that will hopefully make things a little easier to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following...

```
-- Create some test data where NCHAR(6) is the "odd nut" and NCHAR(45) is the kosher value...
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    RandomString NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (RandomString) 
SELECT CONCAT(N'qaz', NCHAR(6), 'wsxcde', NCHAR(45), 'plkm') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(N'5tgbnhh6y6', NCHAR(6), 'wsxe', NCHAR(6), 'pl') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(N'az', NCHAR(45), 'bgtfd', NCHAR(6), 'btgfyyt') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(N'kmioliuj', NCHAR(6), 'drehytj', NCHAR(45), 'gtfhtr') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(N'gf', NCHAR(6), 'nyjuy', NCHAR(6), '8ils') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(N'jhio', NCHAR(45), 'yy', NCHAR(45), 'yj8u7k');

--====================================================================

-- Showing the REPLACE IN the form of a SELECT...
SELECT 
    td.RandomString,
    CleanString = REPLACE(td.RandomString, NCHAR(6), NCHAR(45))
FROM
    #TestData td;

------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Showing the REPLACE IN the form of an UPDATE...
UPDATE td set
    td.RandomString = REPLACE(td.RandomString, NCHAR(6), NCHAR(45))
FROM
    #TestData td
WHERE 
    CHARINDEX(NCHAR(6), td.RandomString) > 0;

------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Prove that we no longer have any NCHAR(6)'s in the values.
SELECT 
    td.RandomString, 
    x.Position,
    CharacterVal = SUBSTRING(td.RandomString, x.Position, 1),
    UnicodeNum = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(td.RandomString, x.Position, 1))
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP (LEN(td.RandomString))
                    Position = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                FROM 
                    sys.all_objects ao
                ) x 
WHERE 
    UNICODE(SUBSTRING(td.RandomString, x.Position, 1)) IN (6, 45);
```

Comment: Thanks bud that was awesome. Is there a resource I can find more information on this topic. Like the codes for all the special characters and identifying and rectifying them. If yes can you please let me know.

Comment: Just do a Google search for "ASCII character set" and/or "UNICODE character set". You'll have no problem finding exactly what you need. If you want to use SQL Server, you can also run the following (just keep in mind that there are several characters such as spaces, tabs, carriage returns & line feeds that don't have graphic symbols)... SELECT TOP 65536 NumericValue = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), ASCII_Set = CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))), UNICODE_Set = NCHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) FROM sys.all_objects ao1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects ao2

Answer (score 2):

Find the ASCII code of the dash by `select ascii('thecharacter')`

Then `UPDATE ABC SET columnname = replace(columname,char(???),'-')`

Comment: If the columns data type is a NCHAR or NVARCHAR, use UNICODE() in place of ASCII().

Comment: @John Cappelletti - I knew the code to replace the character but the thing is that the row count is very big. Can i iterate through the column itself in order to determine where that special character is ?

Comment: You don't have to iterate through anything... Just run it as single UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`UPDATE table
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'weirdcharacter', '-')`

Word of advice, copy your table before doing anything, just in case everything goes wrong:

`SELECT *
INTO tablebackup
FROM table`

However, this won't copy constraints to the new table, so things like primary keys or default values will be lost, unfortunately. I believe there's a way to copy while keeping those with T-SQL, but I'm not sure.